# How to hide the main menu of Texstudio

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

I find the main menu very annoying. I rarely use it since I prefer the shortcuts.

[image: the main toolbar of texstudio]

It there a way to hide it altogether?

Comment: Not tested, but under `preferences->show Advanced Options->Toolsbars` you can adjust the content of the toolbar. I guess, if you remove all icons, the size of the toolbar will shrink to zero.

Comment: yes, it does the same job to right clicking on the Menu itself. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a right click on the menu (not on the icons), 
preferably where the cursor become a cross of arrows, and uncheck all the checkmarks near the voices you don't want to use anymore.

Comment: Well, that doesn't hide the toolbar; it just clears the menus. Oh, yah; clearing all the menus removed the main Menu. Thanks; that helps.

Comment: @Dellu your welcome! Sometimes simple solutions work pretty well.